# word choice: data points or datapoints?

Tags: word-choice

Is that one is correct and the other is not? Or something of brit-english versus us-english? Can I use either?

When I use the Cambridge dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=datapoints together, it advises using with a hyphen!

A quick search on the web gives 
https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/data-point
with a space

I found other references that say that it's just an alternative spelling, but Grammarly doesn't agree with it. Is it wrong to spell datapoints?

- you can send us your `data points` from any hook; or
- you can send us your `datapoints` from any hook;

Comment: No difference. Space is not audible, nor present, so it's a matter of local custom. Consult your correspondents and do what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are alright, but **data point** is much more common.

Regarding dictionaries, Lexico (based off of Oxford Dictionaries) lists **[datapoint](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/datapoint)** as its head entry; Cambridge has **[data point](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/data-point)** in its corpus but not the other. Merriam-Webster has neither.

In media, "data point" is far more common (262 results in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)) than "datapoint" (13 results). Even with an international corpus like NOW ([News on the Web](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/)) "data point" appears 3168 times compared to 155 for "datapoint." Even in JSTOR (an academic database), "datapoint" appears 584 times to "data point"'s 22,876 times.

So while **data point** is much more common, both are attested, so the choice comes down to individual or publication preference.